# C# Tabdelimited text File with multiple column and multiple values in column to datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application, oledbconnection, csv

I am trying to convert my text file having TabDelimited data to Datatable, Text file data shown below:

Row1Col1 Row1Col2 Row1Col3 Row1Col4_0
                                                      Row1Col4_1
                                                      Row1Col4_2

Row2Col1 Row2Col2 Row2Col3 Row2Col4

                  Row2Col2

My code for conversion:

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + file.DirectoryName + ";Extended Properties='text;CharacterSet=" + characterSet + ";HDR=No;FMT=TabDelimited';"))
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", file.Name), con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable("MyTable");
            adp.Fill(tbl);                       
        }
    }
}
```

It's showing me multi line value of column into different column.

Comment: What does this mean: `Row1Col4_0 Row1Col4_1 Row1Col4_2`?

Comment: Well, you can't have *Rows* under just one *Column*.

Comment: Row1Col4_0 Row1Col4_1 Row1Col4_2: <br \> Mean Data of Row 1 and Column 4 with Row1Col4_* multiple data in that column.

Comment: I don't know what that means. It doesn't matter what the content of a Field is. Your description of the data structure doesn't make sense. Each Row has one single value for each Column. You can't have Columns with more than one value.